# How do I group rows with same time from mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
//set $message and run database query
$message .= '<body style="margin: 0;">';
$message .= '<div style="padding: 0 20px;">';
$message .= '<span style="display: block; font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; margin: 25px 0 -15px 0;"> User Activity on ' . $website . ' for ' . $yesterday . '</span>';


//query the database for today's history
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_history WHERE date = '$yesterday' ORDER by name, time, title") 
or die(mysql_error());
$old_user = '';   

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $new_user = $row['uid'];
        if ($new_user != $old_user) {
            $message .= '<br /><br /><hr />' . '<span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">' . $row['name'] . '</span>' . '<br />' . $row['company'] . '<br />' . $row['email'] . '<br />' . $row['phone'] . '<br /><br />';
            $old_user = $new_user;
        }
        $message .= '<ul><li>' . $row['time'] .
    '<ul><li>' . $row['title'] . ' (<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['url'].     '</a> )' . '</li></ul>' . '<br /><br />' .
    '</li></ul>';
    }  


//if no user activity, simply say so
if($new_user == "") {
    $message .= '<br /><br /><hr /><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">No user activity to report</span>';
}

$message .= '</div>';


$message .= '<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 40px; width: 100%; margin: 20px 0 0 0; background: #000; color: #FFF; line-height: 40px; padding: 0 20px;">' .
'Report generated ' . $date . ' ' . $time .
'</div>';

$message .= '</body>';
```

It works beautifully in the mail function. The output email groups like this...

John Doe 
John Doe's Company 
johndoe@johndoeco.com 
800-555-0000

*1:30pm 
   *Video 1

*1:47pm 
   *Video 2

*1:47pm 
   *Video 3

==============================

Instead, I'd like to output like this:

John Doe 
John Doe's Company 
johndoe@johndoeco.com 
800-555-0000

*1:30pm 
   *Video 1

***1:47pm 

   *Video 2 

   *Video 3**

=============================

Can someone please tell me how to make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: database structure is:
  uid ||  name  ||  company  ||  email  ||  phone  ||  date  || time  ||  url  || title  ||

Comment: I know you're not asking about this, but I do want to mention that if you split the code that processes data and the code that creates HTML into two distinct parts, the whole thing becomes a bit more readable and manageable.

Comment: And you already solved your own problem :) The trick you pulled with the old_user and new_user should solve your timing problem too, no?

Comment: @pelshoff - When I put $row['time'] in the if statement, it did not output correctly - only gave one time (in the example, there are two different times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of the current time value using the same technique that you are doing for distinct users (`if ($new_user != $old_user) {`) but for the time value.

Something like

```
if ($new_user != $old_user) {
     //your existing code
     $old_time = null;
     $end_tag = false;
}

if ($old_time == null || $row['time'] != $old_time) {
    $old_time = $row['time'];
    $message .= '<ul><li>' . $row['time'];
    $end_tag = true;
}

$message .= '<ul><li>' . 
             $row['title'] . ' (<a href="' .
             $row['url'] . '">' . $row['url'].     '</a> )' .
            '</li></ul>';

if ($end_tag) {
    $message .= "</li></ul>";
    $end_tag = false;
}
```

Though coding this way starts to get ugly fast and should be split up into functions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$old_time = '';
$video_cache = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    $new_user = $row['uid'];
    if ($new_user != $old_user)
    {
        $message .= '<br /><br /><hr />' . '<span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">' . $row['name'] . '</span>' . '<br />' . $row['company'] . '<br />' . $row['email'] . '<br />' . $row['phone'] . '<br /><br />';
        $old_user = $new_user;
    }
    $new_time = $row['time'];
    if ($old_time != $new_time)
    {
        $video_cache = '<ul><li>' . $old_time . '</li>' . $video_cache . '</ul>';
        $message .= $video_cache;
        $video_cache = '';
    }

    $video_cache .= '<li>' . $row['title'] . ' (<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['url'].     '</a> )' . '</li>';

}
```

Comment: This had some weird results that didn't display all records for each user.

Comment: I think I got the idea of what I'd done wrong. I didn't really mind the actual output as much as the way to get there. I updated it; does this match your expectations more closely?

Comment: I had to change this code...
if ($old_time != $new_time)
    {
        $video_cache = '<ul><li>' .$row['time'] . $old_time . '</li>' . $video_cache . '</ul>';...

added $row['time'] so that I could see the time in the output, however, it eliminated some of the titles, and did not group times as needed.

Comment: But do you have enough ideas to continue? It's rather difficult to code a fully working partial solution in a vacuum. The idea is to cache the video results until you find the next time.